# Java Printing Array based off Another Array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am trying to print an Array, however, I am needing to print the right array, off of an integer from another array.

(i.e.) `arrayInt` contains `2,4,6,5,1`. I want to use a for loop to print the numbers. Then, I want to print the `double` that is corresponding to the `int`. `arrayInt`, that has been sorted, is `1,2,3,4,5` and arrayDouble, that hasn't been sorted, is `2.6,6.9,1.3,2.4,9.8`. After I print `arrayInt[0]`, which is `1`, I want to print the corresponding (in this case the 1<sup>st</sup>) value in `arrayDouble`.

The following code is what I came up with:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
    System.out.printf("%d %.2f\n", sortedNum[k], arrayWeight[(sortedNum[k])]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you kinda answered your own question here, have you tried the code that you specified?

If I understood correctly you want to print something from an array based on the index that is stored in another array, if so, the following code should work (notice I removed the parenthesees from your code):

```
for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
    System.out.printf("%d %.2f\n", sortedNum[k], arrayWeight[sortedNum[k]]);
}
```

This is assuming sortedNum is an array of ints and arrayWeight is an array of floats.

Comment: I have tried to do it as I said, but i am getting this error after printing a few numbers, but it also will not print the write real number correlating to the integer. 

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Comment: The error is exactly what it says, your sortedNum array does not contain 8 items in it. It probbably contains 7 note: arrays are 0 indexed, so the first item would be sortedNum[0]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check size of second array before trying to fetch value from it

```
for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) { 
if (sortedNum[k] < arrayWeight.length)
System.out.printf("%d %.2f\n", sortedNum[k], arrayWeight[sortedNum[k]]); 
}
```